# rails: assets js manifest not picking up specific js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, manifest

I can't get my prints.js file to get picked up by the manifest (I presume that is the issue.)

this is in the appliction.js manifest:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require 'main'
//= require 'cards'
//= require 'prints'
//= require_tree .
```

the cards.js has a console log saying hello like this :

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  console.log('cards js file executed.')
  ...
});
```

When I do the same thing for cards.js like this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  console.log('Prints js file executed.');
});
```

the console only calls out the cards.js console log statement, but not prints.

I restarted rails server, and rebooted my local machine hoping that would pick it up. but no result.
(Rails 4.2)

**EDIT**
I am decided to use the application.js for hosting the function I need.
Though it works, it feels 'cheap' and if anybody has any suggestions of what could make a manifest not include files, that would be greatly appreciated. But I have a temporary solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try without quote like following. after change please restart server

```
//= require main
//= require cards
//= require prints
```

Comment: Tried that, but didn't work. the main and the cards do exist though...but prints not...